# ASP.NET MVC Ajax Error handling

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

How do I handle exceptions thrown in a controller when jquery ajax calls an action?

For example, I would like a global javascript code that gets executed on any kind of server exception during an ajax call which displays the exception message if in debug mode or just a normal error message.

On the client side, I will call a function on the ajax error.

On the server side, Do I need to write a custom actionfilter?

Comment: See [beckelmans post](http://beckelman.net/post/2010/03/18/Handling-Errors-During-Ajax-Calls-With-ASPNET-MVC.aspx) for a good example. Darins answer to this post is good but don't set the correct status code for an error.

Comment: Sadly that link is now broken

Comment: Here is the link on wayback machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20111011105139/http://beckelman.net/post/2010/03/18/Handling-Errors-During-Ajax-Calls-With-ASPNET-MVC.aspx

Answer (score 164, accepted):

If the server sends some status code different than 200, the error callback is executed:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/foo',
    success: function(result) {
        alert('yeap');
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('oops, something bad happened');
    }
});
```

and to register a global error handler you could use the [`$.ajaxSetup()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) method:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('oops, something bad happened');
    }
});
```

Another way is to use JSON. So you could write a custom action filter on the server which catches exception and transforms them into JSON response:

```
public class MyErrorHandlerAttribute : FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
        {
            Data = new { success = false, error = filterContext.Exception.ToString() },
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        };
    }
}
```

and then decorate your controller action with this attribute:

```
[MyErrorHandler]
public ActionResult Foo(string id)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
    {
        throw new Exception("oh no");
    }
    return Json(new { success = true });
}
```

and finally invoke it:

```
$.getJSON('/home/foo', { id: null }, function (result) {
    if (!result.success) {
        alert(result.error);
    } else {
        // handle the success
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, The latter was what I was looking for. So for the asp.net mvc exception, is there a specific way I need to throw it so it can be caught by the jquery error handler?

Comment: @Lol coder, no matter how you throw an exception inside the controller action the server will return 500 status code and the `error` callback will be executed.

Comment: Wouldn't a Status code of 500 be kind of wrong?  To quote this chap http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2011/06/the-good-the-bad-the-ugly-of-rest-apis.html
:
"Failing to realize that a 4xx error means I messed up and a 5xx means you messed up" - where I is the client and you is the server.

Comment: This answer still valid for the newer versions of ASPNET?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I preferred the second method, but I could not find neither the exception type, nor a firendly message i.e. constraint error in **filterContext**. So, is it possible to receive these error details from filterContext or etc?

Comment: @When testing the second code using throw ne Exception(), I encounter "null reference exception" error on OnException. Is this normal? How can I test the second approach (**MyErrorHandlerAttribute**) by raising a mock exception?

Comment: Which one is preferable?

Answer (score 76):

After googling I write a simple Exception handing based on MVC Action Filter:

```
public class HandleExceptionAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest() && filterContext.Exception != null)
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
            {
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
                Data = new
                {
                    filterContext.Exception.Message,
                    filterContext.Exception.StackTrace
                }
            };
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnException(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

and write in global.ascx:

```
 public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
 {
      filters.Add(new HandleExceptionAttribute());
 }
```

and then write this script on the layout or Master page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ajaxError(function (e, jqxhr, settings, exception) {
                       e.stopPropagation();
                       if (jqxhr != null)
                           alert(jqxhr.responseText);
                     });
</script>
```

Finally you should turn on custom error.
and then enjoy it :)

Comment: I can see the error in Firebug butIt is not redirecting to Error page.?

Comment: Thanks for this! should be marked as the answer IMO as its filtering on ajax requests and inherits the correct class rather than what the HandleErrorAttribute inherits

Comment: I think the "Request.IsAjaxRequest()" is not that reliable sometimes.

Comment: For debug configuration it always works but not working always in Release configuration & returns html instead anybody have workaround for such case?

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately, neither of answers are good for me. Surprisingly the solution is much simpler. Return from controller:

```
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, e.Response.ReasonPhrase);
```

And handle it as standard HTTP error on client as you like.

Comment: @Will Huang:the name of the exception instance

Comment: I have to cast the first argument to `int`. Also, when I do this, the result is passed to the `ajax` `success` handler, and not the `error` handler. Is this the expected behavior?

Answer (score 4):

I did a quick solution because I was short of time and it worked ok. Although I think the better option is use an Exception Filter, maybe my solution can help in the case that a simple solution is needed.

I did the following. In the controller method I returned a JsonResult with a property "Success" inside the Data:

```
    [HttpPut]
    public JsonResult UpdateEmployeeConfig(EmployeConfig employeToSave) 
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return new JsonResult
            {
                Data = new { ErrorMessage = "Model is not valid", Success = false },
                ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet
            };
        }
        try
        {
            MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext();

            db.Entry(employeToSave).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();

            DTO.EmployeConfig user = (DTO.EmployeConfig)Session["EmployeLoggin"];

            if (employeToSave.Id == user.Id)
            {
                user.Company = employeToSave.Company;
                user.Language = employeToSave.Language;
                user.Money = employeToSave.Money;
                user.CostCenter = employeToSave.CostCenter;

                Session["EmployeLoggin"] = user;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            return new JsonResult
            {
                Data = new { ErrorMessage = ex.Message, Success = false },
                ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet
            };
        }

        return new JsonResult() { Data = new { Success = true }, };
    }
```

Later in the ajax call I just asked for this property to know if I had an exception:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'UpdateEmployeeConfig',
    type: 'PUT',
    data: JSON.stringify(EmployeConfig),
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.Success) {
            //This is for the example. Please do something prettier for the user, :)
            alert('All was really ok');                                           
        }
        else {
            alert('Oups.. we had errors: ' + data.ErrorMessage);
        }
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
       alert('oh, errors here. The call to the server is not working.')
    }
});
```

Hope this helps. Happy code! :P

Answer (score 4):

In agreement with aleho's response here's a complete example.  It works like a charm and is super simple.

**Controller code**

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> ChildItems()
{
    var client = TranslationDataHttpClient.GetClient();
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("childItems);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            List<WorkflowItem> parameters = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<WorkflowItem>>(content);
            return Json(content, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
        }
    }
}
```

**Javascript code in the view**

```
var url = '@Html.Raw(@Url.Action("ChildItems", "WorkflowItemModal")';

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    url: url,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        // Do something with the returned data
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        // Handle the error.
    }
});
```

Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

For handling errors from ajax calls on the client side, you assign a function to the `error` option of the ajax call.

To set a default globally, you can use the function described here:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup.

Comment: An answer I gave over 4 years ago suddenly gets a down vote? Anyone care to give a reason why?

Comment: Contact SOF and ask their DBA to query who gave the down vote.  Next, message that individual so they can explain. Not just anyone can give a reason why.