# ASP.NET MVC 4, ajax and exception details in JSON

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, error-handling, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to ASP.NET and MVC. In my controller I'm throwing `ArgumentException` on invalid user input. I like the fact that the client is getting some info back in JSON format. But I don't want to send the *whole* stacktrace, just the exception message (which contains a useful, localized explanation of the error).

How should I go about doing this?

I've seen some `Application_Error()` and `FilterException`, but they all seem to be redirecting to a special "error" view, whilst I want to stay on the same page and just print out a dialog with the user-friendly explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this answer [ASP.NET MVC Ajax Error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707755/asp-net-mvc-ajax-error-handling) and also if you need `StatusCode`:

```
filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 500;
```

Comment: The `OnException` method isn't being called. Is there something I need to configure? Note: I didn't change the controller code.

Comment: @Howie You need attribute `[MyErrorHandler]` or global registering, but then you must check request for content type and return json only for `application/json`

Answer (score 1):

```
HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 400
return new ContentResult{Content="My custom error"};
```

In this case ajax will treat response as in error state and you can specify your custom message and get to it from response.responseText property

```
$.ajax({
 .....
error: function(e){
  alert(e.responseText); // your  error message
}
});
```

Comment: I just get "Bad Request" on my IIS server response, but local it's fine! What's happening?