# .Net MVC4 - How to return exception in json format?

Tags: .net, ajax, json, exception, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a MVC4 application where I call a controller action from javascript using jQuery. When an exception occurs in the controller the returned response text is in HTML format. I want it to be in JSON format. How can this be achieved?

I thought some JSON formatter should do the magic on its own...

JavaScript

```
// Call server to load web service methods
$.get("/Pws/LoadService/", data, function (result) {
    // Do stuff here
}, "json")
.error(function (error) { alert("error: " + JSON.stringify(error)) });
```

.Net Controller Action

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult LoadService(string serviceEndpoint)
{
    // do stuff that throws exception

    return Json(serviceModel, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);            
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707755/asp-net-mvc-ajax-error-handling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the error you would be tracking in the error function is related to the request and not the application's error

So i would pass the error details in the Json result, somthing like that :

```
try {
 //....
    return Json(new {hasError=false, data=serviceModel}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
}
catch(Exception e) {
    return Json(new {hasError=true, data=e.Message}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
}
```

And in the client, you can handle with something like that :

```
$.get("/Pws/LoadService/", data, function (result) {

    var resultData = result.d;
    if(resultData.hasError == true) {
      //Handle error as you have the error's message in resultData.data
    }
    else {
        //Process with the data in resultData.data
    }
}, "json") ...
```

Comment: This is the way I have solved this before. I thought that the framework would return exceptions in Json format when specifying JsonResult as return type. Perhaps I can set http header to application/json and get a Json result? I set this to an answer because I think it is a well known solution.