# jquery ajax post with error and success message returned from the server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Here is my view

```
 <div>
    @using ( Html.BeginForm("jQueryPost", "Home",null, FormMethod.Post, new { id="FormPost" }))
    { 
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x=> x.Name)<br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.LastName)<br />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Age)
    <input type=submit value="submit" />
    }
</div>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#FormPost').submit(function (e) {
            //This line will prevent the form from submitting
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('ajax post here');

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: $('#FormPost').attr('action'),
                data: $('#FormPost').serialize(),
                accept: 'application/json',
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert('error: ' + xhr.statusText);
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    alert('resp: ' + response.data);
                }
            });
        });


    });

 </script>
```

This is the Home controller's method the form posts to:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public JsonResult jQueryPost(IndexVM vm)
{
    IndexVM _vm = vm;
    return Json("name posted was: " + _vm.Name);
}
```

When I submit the form I get a 'resp: undefined' in the alert box. How do I return the text "name posted was: .... " back to the view on a successful post?

Also for exceptions when I added this line to the action

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public JsonResult jQueryPost(IndexVM vm)
{
    IndexVM _vm = vm;
    throw new Exception("custom error string from action");
    return Json("name posted was: " + _vm.Name);
}
```

I get the message 'error: Internal Server error'. I want to return the text of the message in the error like so: 'error: custom error string from action'  what is the way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing you code like this,

```
error: function (xhr, status, error) {
    alert('error: ' + xhr.statusTexterror);
},
success: function (response) {
    alert('resp: ' + response);
}
```

***Update***

---

Following are the properties/ methods in `xhr`

- readyState
- status
- statusText
- responseXML and/or responseText when the underlying request responded with xml and/or text, respectively
- setRequestHeader(name, value) which departs from the standard by replacing the old value with the new one rather than concatenating the new value to the old one
- getAllResponseHeaders()
- getResponseHeader()
- statusCode()
- abort()

Comment: thanks will try that out. where can I see a list of properties available under xhr?

Comment: Thanks. I am getting the response now. but the error is still not coming. I get the message undefined in the alert.

Answer (score 2):

If you just throw exceptions in controller actions like that, there isn't a friendly way to get them come back to the front-end. If you notice, you will end up with page html from the default template for exceptions.

On another note, I don't believe this is a good practice since you are just throwing them to get a message coming back.

A good way to handle "errors" from ASP.NET MVC controllers is explained in another question.

[asp-net-mvc-ajax-error-handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707755/asp-net-mvc-ajax-error-handling)