# Throw an exception from an ajax request and catching it

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i am trying to simulate exception management in ASP MVC,

Here is what i have:

```
public JsonResult callit()
{
        throw new HttpException(400, "Bad Request");
}
```

and then i try to call it like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '@Url.Action("callit", "rat", new { area = "test" })',
        cache: 'false',
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert(request.responseText);
        }
});
```

But my application keeps on stopping when the exception is thrown and my error is not being triggered unless i stop the program. What should i do?

Comment: You can write an action filter to handle exceptions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707755/asp-net-mvc-ajax-error-handling

Comment: Use `return new HttpStatusCodeResult(400, "Bad Request");`

Comment: @StephenMuecke i get red lines stating i cannot explicitly convert type web exception to jsonresult

Comment: Just change it to `public ActionResult callit()`

Comment: Oh alright it works. How come it doesn't work if it's Json?

Comment: Because `JsonResult` is a specific type of `ActionResult` which requires you to use `return Json(..)` - refer the [inheritance hierarchy here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: Ah alright, please post an answer so i can accept it. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than throwing an exception, return a [HttpStatusCodeResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httpstatuscoderesult(v=vs.118).aspx) and change you method to `ActionResult`

```cs
public ActionResult callit() // or public HttpStatusCodeResult callit()
{  
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(400, "Bad Request");
}
```