# Pass error message to ajax error handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, webforms

I am calling a controller method from the client using jQuery's `ajax`.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Services/VendorServices.asmx/SendVendorRequestNotifications",
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({ vendorModel: info }),
    timeout: requestTimeOut,
    success: function (data) {
        // Success
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // Error: Would like to display meaningful message here!
    }
});
```

If my `SendVendorRequestNotifications` throws an exception, I'd like to display an error message on the client side. However, I can't seem to get a good message to display to the user.

**textStatus:**

> error

**errorThrown:**

> Internal Server Error

**jqXHR.responseText:**

> {"Message":"One or more errors occurred.","StackTrace":"   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task'1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task'1.get_Result()","ExceptionType":"System.AggregateException"}

As you can see, none of this is useful data. I'd like to be able to gather a more meaningful message on the server and have it available to the `error` handler of the `$.ajax` call.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes. Have a look at this. Can you show the controller code? May be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707755/asp-net-mvc-ajax-error-handling

Comment: @mjw: My actual controller has a lot going on. Not sure what would be of interest. The main thing is that I have a `try...catch` block, and my `catch` block logs the error and then rethrows the exception.

Comment: Can you show the stub? The catch block? Those are likely all that is needed to see what's being returned to the client.

Comment: @mjw: My catch block: `ex = ex.GetInnerMostException(); if (log.IsErrorEnabled)
log.ErrorFormat("{0} failed : {1}", nameof(MakeVendorRequests), ex.Message); throw;`

Comment: @mjw: My method stub: `[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public async Task<string> MakeVendorRequests(ViperVendorViewModel vendorModel)`

Comment: Have you tried the following from the link in my first comment? `return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, e.Response.ReasonPhrase);`

Comment: @mjw: Yes, I was able to pass a specific message this way, thanks. The only trouble is that it doesn't call the `error` handler. The message is passed to the `success` handler. That isn't ideal to the way I'm set up.

Comment: Even if you set the `HttpStatusCode` to an error? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_error

Comment: @mjw: I think I see what's happening. First off, this is actually on a web forms site. (Sorry, I have both WebForms and MVC in this project.) My code is `return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new HttpStatusCodeResult((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message));` But the reason it isn't parsed correctly is because I convert it to a string. But my web method returns a string. So not sure of the best way to handle that. Would you just return an object?

Comment: @mjw: So, returning the object correctly parses the result, but it's still sent to the `success` handler instead of the `error` handler.

Comment: Yes, if you're not returning an `ActionResult` you would need to handle the response manually. Include a `Success = true|false;` in your string response, then add a condition in your success callback.

Comment: @mjw: Thanks, but I have a lot going on, and it's configured to use the `error` handler. So I can create a response like you say, but would prefer to keep it in the error handler so I don't have to duplicate the error handling code. Perhaps it's just not possible.

Comment: @mjw: Feel free to post a regular answer so I can credit the information you've provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To manually pass an `HttpStatusCodeResult`, try this:

```
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, e.Response.ReasonPhrase);
```

Unfortunately, it looks like you're locked in to a return type that won't be processed as an AJAX error, so you'll need to consider changing the return type of your controller action to get the desired outcome. Good luck